# Play Framework 2 upstart for RedHat

Tags: playframework-2.0

Here is upstart configuration for Ubuntu.
How can I adapt it for RedHat?

Questions are:

1. There is no start-stop-daemon on RedHat.
2. start/stop on runlevel - are values ok for RedHat?
3. Any other corrections?

Thank you!

```
# /etc/init/linka.conf
description "Linka"

env USER=linka
env GROUP=nogroup
env HOME=/home/backlink/web2
env JAVA_OPTS="-Xms128M -Xmx512m -server -Dhttp.port=9002 -Dhttp.address=127.0.0.1 -Dconfig.file=/home/backlink/application.conf -Dlogger.file=/home/backlink/logger.xml"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [016]

respawn
expect daemon

pre-start script
  rm -f ${HOME}/RUNNING_PID
end script

exec start-stop-daemon \
  --pidfile ${HOME}/RUNNING_PID --chuid $USER:$GROUP \
  --exec ${HOME}/start --background --start \
  -- $JAVA_OPTS > /dev/null 2>&1
```

**UPDATE**

Currently solved this with such upstart job: http://pastie.org/4335691
But I'm not sure if using & at the end of java call (to put it at background) is a good idea.

Comment: "I'm not sure if using & at the end of java call (to put it at background) is a good idea." besides not being a good idea or not i don't think that even works! did you test it?

Comment: Yes, it works of course - that is why I placed it here.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example for Play1, should be easy to adapt for Play2: https://gist.github.com/993459

In the example above, the start runlevel is 345. You'll have to use [chkconfig](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/chkconfig8.html) to install this script.

Comment: Thanks for the link. However I'm looking for upstart job, not init.d script.